# Set true/false returned to yes/no in Dropdown

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I have the following piece of code:

```
   <div *ngSwitchCase="'Boolean'">
        <select *ngIf="attribute.IsWritable" [(ngModel)]="animal[attribute.AttributeKey]">
            <option (value)="animal[attribute.AttributeKey]==true">Yes</option>
            <option (value)="animal[attribute.AttributeKey]==false">No</option>
        </select>
        <span *ngIf="!attribute.IsWritable && attribute.IsReadable && animal[attribute.AttributeKey] ">Yes</span>
        <span *ngIf="!attribute.IsWritable && attribute.IsReadable && !animal[attribute.AttributeKey]">No</span>             
     </div>
```

I want to change the drop down to display yes or now based on the value returned from animal[attribute.AttributeKey] which is either true or false. How can I go about achieving this ? . Any help is appreciated. Also how can I keep the value returned here to be selected by default ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try binding options `value` as input:

```
<select *ngIf="attribute.IsWritable" [(ngModel)]="animal[attribute.AttributeKey]">
  <option [value]="true">Yes</option>
  <option [value]="false">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as you expect because binding in `select` to `value` option will return

> string

`'true'` or `'false'`

`<select *ngIf="attribute.IsWritable" [(ngModel)]="animal[attribute.AttributeKey]">
  <option [value]="true">Yes</option>
  <option [value]="false">No</option>
</select>`

So in that case the next part should be as below:

```
<span *ngIf="attribute.IsWritable && attribute.IsReadable && animal[attribute.AttributeKey] === 'true' ">Yes</span>
<span *ngIf="attribute.IsWritable && attribute.IsReadable && animal[attribute.AttributeKey] === 'false'">No</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way that I've approached it:

```
        <div>
          <label for="active" class="form-label">Active State</label>
          <select id="active" class="form-select" #op (change)="data.active = op.value == 'true'">
            <option value="true" selected>True</option>
            <option value="false">False</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

By using the attribute tag on the select html you can then access its value and do a comparison to set the properties values accordingly